# Web3 v1 nodejs call to get Ethereum accounts via RPC call

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I cannot understand how to get a listing of my accounts using the new Web3 v1 JS lib. It use to be easy: `web3.eth.accounts`.

Does anyone know how to get a simple listing of accounts using Web3 v1 JS lib in node?

This returns more data than just the accounts, so I'm at a loss here.

`web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(accts) { 
    accounts = accts 
})
```

Accounts are then available as web3.eth.accounts use to be; so `accounts[0]`, `accounts[1]`, etc. are now available. I was able to resolve it using the above line of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
$node -v v8.10.0 
$node
> web3.version 
'1.0.0-beta.30' 
> web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(accts) { accounts = accts } ) Promise 
  { 
    _bitField: 0, 
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined, 
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined, 
    _promise0: undefined, 
    _receiver0: undefined
  } 
> web3.eth.accounts[0] 
undefined 
> web3.eth.accounts 
undefined 
> web3.eth.accts 
undefined
```

```